# Проксирование Nginx (проблема с сертификатами)

Tags: nginx, proxy, certbot

Доброго времени суток!

Проблема следующая.

Есть две vps-ки (условно vps А и vps Б).
На обоих установлен nginx, привязаны доменки (сделаны записи А).

Хочу использовать "А" как прокси, т.е. все запросы, которые поступают на А:443 уходили на Б:443.

Серты получаю с помощью команды: certbot --nginx --register-unsafely-without-email

До настройки routing, ввожу в браузере домены, которые прикреплены к vps-кам A и Б. Все хорошо, везде connection secure.

Конфиг А после получения сертификата:

```
server {
  root /var/www/domain.com;
  index index.html;
  server_name domain.como;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Ce>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by >
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

Но после того, как я прописываю routing, а именно:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination ip(vps-ки Б):443
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

прокси работает, но пишет, что connection not secure.

не могу понять, в чем причина.

Comment: что-то в конфиге Nginx не видно никакого проксирования

Comment: На вашем А nginx не нужен. На вашем Б нужны оба сертификата и, соответственно, два блока server. Ну и неясно зачем тут вообще нужен А.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы на самом деле хотите? У вас оба сервера, А и Б, торчат в интернет или только А, а Б у вас во внутренней сети? В таком случае у вас SSL на А, и с него обычный proxe_pass  (у вас же сейчас не проксирование, а перенаправление) на 80 порт на Б, который не слушает внешние подключения. Если оба сервера слушают внешний интернет, то суть задумки не ясна